# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’ using simple function

Tags: haskell

I am implementing a function in Haskell: [image: function]

I have written

```
f x k = h x k

h x i = x^i/factorial i


factorial n = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]
```

where `h` is a helper function that will be used in `f` function when summing. But right now when I try to use the function I get this error:

```
<interactive>:109:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: Exactly what do you write to query the system?

Comment: The error message mentions a use of `print` but you share no such code. Please share the code which actually causes the error.

Comment: I just typed `h 1 1` in GHCI. sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we inspect the type of `h`, we see:

```
h :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
```

So it means that your number should be both `Fractional` and `Integral`. Although strictly speaking you can create numbers in Haskell that are members of both typeclasses, it does not make much sense. A number that is `Integral` is not `Fractional` and vice versa.

The reason this happens is because we make use of `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a`. It thus requires both the numerator and denominator to be of the same type, and members of `Fractional`. This thus means that `factorial i` should have that type `a`, and thus by extent `i` itself. But `i` should be integral because of the use of [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-).

You can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert the given integral number to another type that is a member of `Num`:

```
h :: (Floating a, Integral b) => a -> a -> b
h x i = x^i / fromIntegral (factorial i)
```

This gives us for example:

```
Prelude> h 2 1
2.0
Prelude> h 2 2
2.0
Prelude> h 2 3
1.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but still a relevant observation: your function can be calculated more efficiently (and will be more fun to implement) when you rewrite it like this:

[image: Alternative form to g(x,k)]